# Getting meta data on a video that is hidden [Vimeo]

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth, vimeo, vimeo-api

Environment: ASP.NET 4.0 Forms running on Windows Server 2008
Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
DotNetOpenAuth (Just learning)

Trying to do something quite simple, creating a video archive using Vimeo as the host but we want them on Vimeo, just embedding on our website. We uploaded a few sample videos and set them to be hidden and restricted embedding to only our domain. When testing it, they embed just fine but when we send a request for the video info (http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/*.xml), the server responds 404 not found. If we go back and set it to anyone can view, we get the response information we need. How can we get the video information and still keep the video hidden?

```
private string GetVideoXML(string id)
{
    try
    {
        // URL
        String url = string.Format("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/{0}.xml", id);

        // Make the request
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        string token = "<My authorization token from Vimeo API>";           
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + token);

        // Show me the money?
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();  // Throws an exception, 404 not found

        // Read XML
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        String responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //Close
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();

        // Show me the money!
        return responseData;            

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // You has some 'splaining to do
        litError.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL you provided (http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/*.xml) is the Simple API. The Simple API can not access private data (as mentioned in the docs).

The Simple API has also been deprecated in favor of the new API (https://developer.vimeo.com/api). The new API supports private videos with the proper authentication tokens.

Vimeo does not currently provide an ASP library for the new API, but it's worth keeping an eye on https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries to see if that has changed.

Even without a library, it shouldn't be too hard to track this down yourself.

1. Generate your API token on your app page, at https://developer.vimeo.com/apps under the "authentication" tab
2. Find your API endpoint in the docs: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints.
3. Make an HTTP request to that API endpoint with your token. The token should be applied via the Authorization header like so: `Authorization: Bearer {token}`

With the proper endpoint and credentials, you should see a JSON response including all of your videos, including private videos.